# Comparing dictionary values and sorting some out

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I have a dictionary with a random generated key (ex. mApd12iX6V1zrUtn) and three values stored in a list (ex. [823583862, 717, 4979]). Those three values are the mass, a x-coordinate and a y-coordinate. I want to compare all the coordinates of every item/object in that dictionary and combine them if the coordinates are up to 10 apart from each other.

I tried to iterate over the dictionary in a nested loop.

```
new_obj_list = {}
for item in obj_list:
    new_obj_list[item] = obj_list[item]

for item in obj_list:

    for item1 in obj_list:

        if item != item1 and obj_list[item][1]-10 < obj_list[item1][1] < obj_list[item][1]+10:

            new_mass = obj_list[item1][0] + obj_list[item][0]
            new_posx = obj_list[item][1]
            new_posy = obj_list[item][2]
            new_data = [new_mass, new_posx, new_posy]
            new_obj_list[item] = new_data

        if item != item1 and obj_list[item][2]-10 < obj_list[item1][2] < obj_list[item][2]+10:

            new_mass = obj_list[item1][0] + obj_list[item][0]
            new_posx = obj_list[item][1]
            new_posy = obj_list[item][2]
            new_data = [new_mass, new_posx, new_posy]
            new_obj_list[item] = new_data

print(len(obj_list))
print(len(new_obj_list))
```

The length of obj_list is the same as the length of new_obj_list. I was expecting new_obj_list to be way smaller than obj_list, because only the sorted items should get stored in new_obj_list.

Answer (score 1):

When you combine two items, you need to delete the item you didn't overwrite.

You overwrite whatever list is keyed by 'item' but you don't delete whatever list is keyed by 'item1', so you end up with the same amount of keys after you have iterated through your dictionary.

Or, you could initialize new_obj_list as an empty dict instead of copying over items from obj_list before doing any combining.

Comment: Either I'm doing it wrong or initializing new_obj_list as an empty dict doesn't work anyway. I think my sorting statements don't work like they're supposed to. If I initialize the dict as an empty one I get exactly the same result as before.

Comment: Can you give a small test case that gives an incorrect output, and include what output you're expecting?

Comment: obj_list = {'iMbvRx9ws3gAut4Lkl4': [324453, 2434, 33], '7Lt3f0aARp5uV': [2314324, 2443, 5000]}
I'm expecting them to combine, because the x-coordinate is in range of 10. So my expected output would be obj_list = {''iMbvRx9ws3gAut4Lkl4': [2638777‬, 2434, 33]}

Comment: Alright, I think your problem is that you're looping through all items in both your inner and outer loops. So for the above example, you would compare the first item with the second item, and add it to your new dict. But then you would compare the second item with the first item on the second iteration of the outer for loop, and add the second item to your new dict, resulting in a new dict of the same length. Also, the second if should be an elif, because you probably don't want to add an item twice if both it's x and y values are in range of some other dict entry.

Comment: Okay, sounds correct :D. How can I solve my problem then ? Just by changing the second if statement to and elif ?

Comment: I would say change your loops as well. You can use key_list=mydict.keys() to get a list of keys. And change your outer for loop to something like "for i in range(len(key_list)):" and your inner loop to something like "for j in range(i, len(key_list)):" then find which keys to compare by indexing your key_list with i and j

Answer (score 0):

Of course the length is the same as the old dictionary! You are coping (in first loop) it and modifying some elements (in second loop)! You should instead leave the new dictionary empty and append new elements.

Also I don't know if it will change much but I suggest to calculate your distance this way:

```
#remove first copy loop

#inside your double for loop do:
dSQ = (old_dict[item][1] - old_dict[item1][1])**2 + (old_dict[item][2] - old_dict[item1][2])**2
if dSQ < 10**2:
   #combine your objects as you did before
   new_dict[item1] = new_data
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion in terms of combining the distance. I think that's the problem with my code. Even after trying to initialize the new dict as an empty one I get the same results. But I want to combine my objects if either the x-coordinates or the y-coordinates are in range. I think your solution will only combine the objects if both coordinates are in range.

Comment: Oh I see, so leave your distance calculation the same as before but you shouldn't copy the values as you do in the first loop but instead add them as you combine them in your second double-loop